# Release apk crashing when executed (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Release apk crashes when loaded onto mobile with the following error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so caused by: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor result: 0 result: 0

This is the logcat (Hermes is disabled)

```
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.panelist/lib-main flags = 1]
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~ZEFLAMFG5cZrOBL45-PwSA==/com.panelist-q4UYB-63HdGP-lK7ivTlYQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      Native lib dir: /data/app/~~ZEFLAMFG5cZrOBL45-PwSA==/com.panelist-q4UYB-63HdGP-lK7ivTlYQ==/lib/arm64
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W   result: 0
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:918)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary(HermesExecutor.java:25)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:19)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:370)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:319)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.panelist.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.702 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1223)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7094)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:273)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8279)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 System.err              com.panelist                         W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
2023-10-31 21:40:07.703 30262-30262 AndroidRuntime          com.panelist                         D  Shutting down VM
2023-10-31 21:40:07.704 30262-30262 AndroidRuntime          com.panelist                         E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.panelist, PID: 30262
                                                                                                    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so caused by: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor result: 0 result: 0
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:918)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:352)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:319)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
                                                                                                        at com.panelist.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7094)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:273)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8279)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so caused by: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor result: 0
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:918)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:640)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadDependencies(DirectorySoSource.java:121)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:71)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.loadLibrary(UnpackingSoSource.java:477)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:860)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:352) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42) 
                                                                                                        at com.panelist.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:273) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8279) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Runtime.java:1126)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:931)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1625)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:405)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:77)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.loadLibrary(UnpackingSoSource.java:477)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:860)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:640) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadDependencies(DirectorySoSource.java:121) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:71) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.loadLibrary(UnpackingSoSource.java:477) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:860) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:352) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42) 
                                                                                                        at com.panelist.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:273) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8279) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

Solution 1

```
dependencies {
    // ...

    if (enableHermes) {
+       implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
+           exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
+       }
-       def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
-       debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
-       releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Solution 2

```
implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
```

to

```
implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:" + <YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_VERSION>) { // From node_modules
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
```

for more solution check this [git issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33120)

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: Please add your build.gradle file to your question

Comment: Is your problem solved?